# How can I add a click event to a button I'm building in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function:

```
var ButtonChoice = function(key, type, img, label){
this.key = key;
this.type = type;
this.img = img;
this.label = label;
this.getButton = function(){
 return "<img src='img/" + this.img + "' type='" + this.type + "' id='" + 
         this.key + "' class='ButtonsChoice' description='" + this.label + 
         "' />" 
 };
};
```

And I need to add click function to this images. My question is how to do that?

Comment: Add it to the DOM first, then with a reference to the `Element` you can invoke `element.addEventListener('click', function () { // do something });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating the image as a HTML string you can just create it dynamically using JavaScript, this will allow you to attach the `click` event dynamically using `onclick`.

This is how should be your code:

```
var ButtonChoice = function(key, type, img, label) {
  this.key = key;
  this.type = type;
  this.img = img;
  this.label = label;
  this.getButton = function() {
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = "img/" + this.img;
    image.type = this.type;
    image.id = this.key;
    image.className = "ButtonsChoice";
    image.description = this.label;
    image.onclick = function(){
        //Put your code here
    }
    return image;
  };
};
```

**Note:**

I don't see why you are using a `type` attribute for your images, `type` attribute is generally used with inputs and buttons, please check the [MDN **HTML attribute reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) table for more details.

Comment: Hhhhh @Liam yes this is the most basic and reasonable way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add onclick function to your returned value:

```
 return "<img src='img/" + this.img + "' type='" + this.type + "' id='" + 
         this.key + "' class='ButtonsChoice' description='" + this.label + 
         "' onclick='yourFunc();' />"
```

Comment: While this would work, it's very old-school and generally recommended that you don't use `onclick=`

Answer (score -1):

Add this event listener to a `document.ready()` event listener:

```
$('.ButtonsChoice').click(function(e){
    ... do something ...
});
```

Of course, this treats all button the same that have that class...

Comment: This will likely not work.  The fact that `ButtonChoice` is a function *implies* it will be called after document ready.  So you'd need event delegation.

Comment: this won't work as the button is dynamically created, you'd need to use on and event delegation

Answer (score -1):

you can do it this way,

```
<img src="example.gif" onclick="a('hello')">
```

in the above line inside the img tag add a onclick event which will invoke a function *a(value)*